# XCode 9 - Can't link an internal framework for test target of iPad app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad, linker-errors

We're trying to setup unit tests for our iPad app but when trying to import a file, in this example `Menu.h`, in our test file called `MenuTest.h`, it fails to build the tests because `Menu.h` imports our other project, which is built as a framework within the same workspace. This import seems to fail.

---

```
// Menu.h
...
@import InternalFramework;
...
```

---

```
// MenuTest.h

#import <XCTest/XCTest.h>
#import "Menu.h"

@interface OurInterface : XCTestCase

@end

@implementation OurTests

#import "Menu.h"

- (void) setUp {}

- (void) tearDown {}

- (void) firstTest {
    Menu *menu = [[Menu alloc] init];
}
```

---

We've both googled and found other questions regarding these things but still have not been able to get it to work. Is it not supposed to otherwise keep the same dependency settings as normal when you compile for testing?